# How to change the input array using a TextBox?

Tags: c#

How to change the array to enter the desired format in TextBox'e?
Here is the code:

```
private static readonly string[] Extensions = new string[] { textbox1.text };
```

In the fields of { } must be changed to textbox!

In the text box I want so I can introduce such formats using a comma! txt,png,ico,dll

Or better using List?

```
 List<string> mylist = new List<string>() { "*.txt" };
```

[image]

Wish I could enter my desired formats is not in the code {"*.txt"}! And TextBox'e .

P.S:

```
 private static string[] Extensions = new string[] { "*.txt" };
    //public static string[] Extensions;
    public static void extractExtensions(string s)
    {
        Extensions = s.Split(',');
    }
```

And how do I assign values to string [] { "of the textbox"};

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you only want ".xxx" strings separated by a comma, to be allowed in the text box?

Comment: you can use `string.Join(", ", YourArray)` and array must be like this. `{ "txt", "ico", "etc" };`

Comment: do you want to write the extensions into your textbox and then extract them into an array or list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not easy to understand what you are really having problems with, but try this:

```
textbox1.Text = String.Join(",", Extensions);
```

the reverse would be from textbox --> array:

```
string [] singleExtensions = textbox1.Text.Split(',');
```

this would give you all the elements which were separated by a `,` and dump them into the array.

Or if you prefer Lists:

```
List<string> singleExtensions = textbox1.Text.Split(',').ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

Ok since you don't want to post more code, I make a wild guess:

I imagine you have a Windows Forms application and a `TextBox` in a `Form1`.
You also should have an instance of the class that you want to use in there.
Let's assume the class is called `MyClass` and it has an array for the extensions, and a method `extractExtensions` to extract the extensions:

```
public class MyClass
{
    string [] singleExtensions;

    public void extractExtensions(string s)
    {
        singleExtensions = s.Split(',');

    }    
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    // instance of class:
    MyClass _myClass = new MyClass();
}
```

at a certain point in your `Form` you want to call the method of your class and pass the content of the textbox like this:

```
_myClass.extractExtensions(textbox1.Text);
```

and voilà.

**EDIT 2:**

Say for example you want to extract the extensions with a button click, then you call this method inside the `btn1_Click` event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    // instance of class:
    MyClass _myClass = new MyClass();


    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _myClass.extractExtensions(textbox1.Text);
    }
}
```

if you made this method `static` like in your post you would call it like this:

```
MyClass.extractExtensions(textbox1.Text);
```

Comment: please post more code. especially the relevant classes. Preferably the code for the `Form` with the `TextBox` and also the code for the `class` that you use. You can use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40506454/edit) button below your post.  Do you know how to call a method in a class from another class?

Comment: I think I know what you are talking about, but I am not sure unless I see the necessary code

Comment: I can not figure out

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to post the code of the Windows Forms and the class that you use not only the method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of desired extensions

```
  var extensions = new List<string> { ".txt", ".png", ".dll" };
```

you can join the items to compose a string and show it in a text box

```
  txtExtensions.Text = string.Join(",", extensions);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for example: how to call it from class?